Interpretation of geodesics in Kerr metric when approaching the event horizon
I'm learning about the Kerr metric and Kerr black holes from the book "General Relativity: An Introduction for Physicists, M.P.Hobson" and I'm interested in an interpretation for the equatorial geodesics. In the book it keeps saying that the $\phi$ and $t$ coordinates are "bad" coordinates. This is portrayed in the geodesics as $\dot \phi \propto \frac{1}{\Delta}$ and $\dot t \propto \frac{1}{\Delta}$ so as $r \rightarrow r_+,r_-$ the temporal and angular derivatives diverge. This is shown in the following figure in the book

Here I understand the behaviour of a free falling object from infinity, as the object approaches the outer event horizon, a far away observer would see the object orbit the black hole indefinitely and never go inside it. However, I don't understand why once it crosses the outermost event horizon the object would appear to rotate in the opposite direction and same with the time. It seems that the object would be rotating and moving through time in a negative direction. How can this be? Am I misinterpreting something?
Other than that, the book presents the Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates as a fix for these "bad" coordinates. Is there an easy way to derive the geodesics using this coordinate system? In this case what would the difference be between the new graphs and the ones shown here?
Lastly, in my general relativity course they made us use a code that numerically calculates the equatorial trajectories in a Schwarzschild black hole and we could see how using a far away point of reference a free falling object could never cross the event horizon but using the proper time the object crosses the horizon, can something similar be done for this metric?

The answer to your last question is surely yes. You can numerically solve the geodesic equation for any metric, and equatorial geodesics in a fairly symmetrical situation like Kerr will be easier than for a generic metric. Obviously the devil is in the details for how hard that would be in practice. Numerically solving geodesics in Kerr is one thing that the paper associated with the movie Interstellar did (they weren't the first to study null geodesics in Kerr, they cite Carter 1968 and Bardeen 1972, but that is just a famous recent example).


Mikel Solaguren wrote: "In the book it keeps saying that the ϕ and t coordinates are "bad" coordinates."

I wouldn't call them bad, they just use the reference frame of an external observer.

Mikel Solaguren asked: "Other than that, the book presents the Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates as a fix for these "bad" coordinates. Is there an easy way to derive the geodesics using this coordinate system?"

It's as easy as deriving the geodesics in Boyer Lindquist or Doran Raindrop coordinates, just solve the geodesic equation as shown here at (11) (for the transformation see a/772647/24093).

Mikel Solaguren asked: "In this case what would the difference be between the new graphs and the ones shown here?"

Here is a photon falling into the black hole, in Boyer Lindquist coordinates where t is the proper time of the static bookkeeper at infinity it ends up corotating at the horizon:

while in Eddington Finkelstein style Kerr Schild coordinates where the timestamps are defined such that ingoing polar photons have dr/dt=-c it passes through the ring to exit into the negative space antiverse (assuming the maximal extension of an eternal black hole):

If you plot a circular equatorial orbit at constant r you won't see any difference though, that will of course stay circular in all coordinates.

While mathematically your animations are correct of course, they don’t have a physical meaning in real life. The Kerr spacetime is hyperbolic obeying causal order, at least in every universe outside the horizon. The cosmological time to cross the horizon or antihorizon is infinite. So on your animation of a particle passing through, when it crosses the horizon, the external universe dies beyond the infinite cosmological future. And then it must cross the antihorizon before the universe, which must be eternal, is born beyond the infinite cosmological past. None of this makes any physical sense.

@safesphere - The question was not about the physical validity of the Kerr interior, but about the geodesics in the Kerr metric, so it is what it is. In an astrophysical black hole there probably is no ring singularity since that is gravitaionally repulsible everywhere except θ=π/2 and therefore unlikely to form, then you might get a torus of the former star's material whirling around inside the inner horizon or something like that instead, but that is not the topic of this question.

@safesphere wrote: "when it crosses the horizon, the external universe dies beyond the infinite cosmological future" - the infinite time lapse is for a local observer at constant r where the effect is purely gravitational. If you fall in, the kinematic time dilation will cancel the gravitational time lapse in your frame of reference, so in the frame of the infalling observer the universe doesn't die while he falls in, that is only the case in the frame of the external observer where the gravitational and kinematic components don't cancel each other.

In Gullstrand Painlevé style coordinates where the velocity of the local clocks is the exact escape velocity (free falling from infinity) the gᵗᵗ is therefore 1, in that frame there is no time dilation between the free faller and the exterior stars since the gravitational time lapse equals the kinematic time dilation and cancels perfectly. The Kerr equivalent of those coordinates are called Doran raindrop coordinates, see https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0411060 at page 6

Be that as it may, it is irrelevant. The fact that the universe dies when a falling object touches the horizon is coordinate independent due to the global hyperbolicity of spacetime - no external event is in the future lightcone of any event at the horizon. Also, doesn’t this kinematic effect depend on direction? The universe in the perpendicular direction still dies, doesn’t it? SR is a weird theory despite a simple math.

@safesphere wrote: "Also, doesn’t this kinematic effect depend on direction?" - The Doppler depends on the direction, but the kinematic time dilation does not. For the blueshift of the background sky in the frames of falling and stationary observers see here and here

Ah yes, of course. The hyperbolic geometry is super weird.

This isn't a comprehensive answer (and also a bit too long to be a comment) because I'm only going to address the first question. While the object is orbiting the hole, it is affected by the curvature and also the angular momentum. The part of the figure to the right shows the object being increasingly affected by the angular momentum as it nears the event horizon. However, if a horizon gets crossed, the curvature takes over and the object (at rest) follows a unidirectional path unaffected by whether the angular momentum was greater or lesser. That is to say, inside the horizon, the time to arrival at the (in this case) ring singularity will depend only upon the mass of the hole.

Forget the ring singularity, it’s in the strange world where time goes in loops. The real object of interest inside is the inner horizon. It is shaped as an infinitely long cylinder (sort of). If the hole rotation slows down and stops, this cylinder shrinks down and becomes an infinitely long line, which is the Schwarzschild singularity (see my Photoshop diagram here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2929400 ). So the Schwarzschild singularity is the cylinder of the inner horizon shrunk down to a line. Can we say that “inside” an infinitely thin line there is a dot of “ringularity”?

Wooke wrote: "That is to say, inside the horizon, the time to arrival at the (in this case) ring singularity will depend only upon the mass of the hole." - Your answer is wrong, even in Schwarzschild the proper time from the horizon to the singularity depends on the initial conditions and can be everything between Δτ→0 and Δτ→πGM/c³, even more so with Kerr where you can even have trajectories inside the horizon who never reach the singularity.

@Yukterez Thank you for adding those points. In a true Kerr black hole (disregarding Hobson's figure made from Kerr's coordinates only) there is no singularity to reach. My answer only attempts to confirm that Mikel is not misinterpreting what is shown. I'm very glad you brought an answer. I look forward to reading that Russian paper even though white holes aren't my cup of reality tea.

@Wookie Once we get you to a thousand, you’ll see the hidden stuff and know the truth behind the curtain. I’m too just a couple of clicks short on the math site…

@Wookie “Caused by what though? Gravitational implosion?” - Yes. The key is that time is relative and thus its direction can vary. Normally it is to the future, but heavy objects bend it toward themselves. Then you, while moving forward in time, also shift toward a heave object - you fall. So gravity simply is a result of time being bent by a heavy object toward itself. Black holes’s gravity is so strong that it turns time completely. At the horizon the turn is 45 degrees, meaning that time no longer points in the timelike direction (future) and not yet in the spacelike direction … (cont.)

@Wookie … (to the center), but is on the fence in between (lightlike). Once the horizon is crossed, if you believe in fairytales, time bends a bit more and start pointing more toward the inside than toward the external future. So the radial direction inside becomes a direction in time, not in space. Let me put it this way. If time is a highway, say, to the North (future) and we drive nearby in two cars, then a black hole is an exit to the West. You take it and keep driving, your time moves on intact, but I see that your movement to my future has stopped. So I see your time dilated and stopped.

@Wookie And this is where everyone gets lost. Once you’ve turned in and are at the horizon, how far is to the “center”? Oh, that’s simple, everyone knows this: the distance is the Schwarzschild radius, right? Wrong. The distance is zero. The horizon is at the “center”. Wait… what??? Don’t give me this! Everyone knows the singularity is inside the horizon. You first cross the horizon and then fly toward the singularity, right? Wrong again. The radius is no longer space, but time. You don’t fly in time - you wait. You never “cross” the horizon, it already is at the center. You just wait there.

@safesphere Not in (for example) Gullstrand–Painlevé coordinates https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gullstrand%E2%80%93Painlev%C3%A9_coordinates.  All that "radius becomes time" palaver is down to choice of coordinates.

@m4r35n357 Thanks for your opinion, but my description is in the view of a static remote observer and the GP coordinates have nothing to do with it. Much can be said about these coordinates, because their deep meaning is not the same as how they are superficially described and for this reason they are misleading to non-specialists. However this is a separate topic for another place at another time.

@safesphere no thanks necessary, and it is not an opinion. The statement "The radius is no longer space, but time" is coordinate-dependent!

@m4r35n357 - correct, the space and time only switch for tachyons who are stationary behind the horizon, real observers who are not stationary behind the horizon have no such switch. In standard Schwarzschild Droste coordinates the local clocks and rulers are defined as stationary, so no wonder you get crazy spacetimeflips with them since they must be accelerated tachyons in order to stay stationary.

@m4r35n357 Thanks again for your irrelevant contribution to the conversation you weren’t a part of. No one here was making or cared for coordinate independent statements.

@Yukterez I am well aware of your long love for local observers and I’d love to debunk your tachyon creativity, but sadly this is not the place for this conversation. Perhaps we can have a joyful fight in another thread :)

@safesphere - if you google for the Schwarzschild fiducial observers (FIDO) you will find that they are stationary in the standard diagonal coordinates. The fact that only spacelike observers can stay stationary at r<rs is also a well known fact, and an other word for spacelike observers is tachyons, so I don't see how you would debunk anything I said. In Boyer Lindquist we have corotating ZAMOs instead of stationary FIDOs so we don't get a space/time-flip at the ergosphere, but other than that the principle is the same

@Yukterez Please expand your view beyond your horizon to notice the “not the place” remark.

@safesphere, thank me as much as you want - I'm out!

@safesphere wrote: "So the Schwarzschild singularity is the cylinder of the inner horizon shrunk down to a line" - You are confusing r with x, y or z. The singularity with spacelike t and timelike r is not a line but a surface since a radius is not in one but in all directions. If you replace r with t the singularity is still at all θ and φ with a radius larger than 0 when t>0. I know you don't want to talk about that any more, but since you repeat it again and again in many comments this needs to be debunked once and for all

@Yukterez Your math is almost always good, so it is surprising to see such a simple error from you here :) Let's rewind. A Schwarzschild singularity is a coordinate location (excised from the metric manifold) described by the equation of $r=0$. In 4-dimensional Schwarzschild coordinates this equation describes a Euclidean line, nothing else. I never downvote, but your answer on the math site is misleading, so I must. Sorry, but you've asked for it :) What you are describing is not the singularity itself, but the manifold asymptotically close to it ($r\ll r_s$). We have no disagreement on this.

@Yukterez Sorry for the downvote :) I am just surprised seeing your objection on something we basically agree upon. Mathematically the limit of a cylinder with the radius tending to zero is a line. This doesn't imply that a line is a cylinder. With a finite radius, no matter how small, the cylinder is a surface, as your link shows. We do agree on this. However, with a zero radius, there is no cylinder anymore, so a line is not a surface. Sorry for this 5th grade math trivia :) Plus I've gone even beyond this, as you quote me "singularity is the cylinder", so your objection is truly puzzling.

@safesphere - I don't care about the downvote, what I said is still true and I won't lie for upvotes.

@Yukterez Except it's not true, as explained logically time and again. Your response is not logical, but like "it is true, because I say so". Sorry, not good enough for either physics or math. Also, the downvote is not to hurt your feelings, I wouldn't do this. It is because that question is important and often referenced, so it must be pointed out that your answer there is incorrect. Sorry...

Here is the proper view of the diagram you linked above. For any $r>0$ the causal path between the falling observers is bounded, they are in a timeslice that is a hypersurface. The $r=0$ coordinate location (singularity) is not a part of the metric space. Hence the concept of causal path is undefined there. $r=0$ is the equation of a Euclidean line. The fact that the causal connection is finite for any $r>0$ does not prove that $r=0$ is a hypersurface, same as a zero radius cylinder is not a surface. There is no logical connection between the causal path and the geometry of the singularity.

@Yukterez I’ve looked at your older posts and canceled someone’s unjust downvotes :)
